# Why isn't my div showing up properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently making a game with HTML, CSS and jQuery. This will be the usual falling block avoid game.

I am having trouble with my jQuery though. When I select a theme **(only dark theme is currently "working")**, the player doesn't show up:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#options').change(function() { // NOTE: all themes have capital letters on colors
    if ($(this).val() === 'Dark') {
      $("#game").css("background-color", "black");
      $("#player").css({
        "background-color": "white" // using CSS function in case you want to add other stuff
      });
    }
  });

  $("#play").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#options").hide();
    $("#player").show();
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.block {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute
}
#game {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 550px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  margin: 2% 10%;
}
#player {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute
}
#play {
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
#options {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trash Fall - Game</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- adding jQuery to the script -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="main_title">Color Drop</h1>

  <div id="game">

    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <select id="options">
      <option value="none">none (choose one in order to play)</option>
      <option value="Dark">Dark</option>
      <option value="Light">Light</option>
      <option value="Blue_White">Blue/White</option>
      <option value="Red_White">Red/White</option>
    </select>

    <div id="player"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

---

---

**NOTE**: I am seeing that this is working in this snippet, however it is not working on github (where I am creating the game): [example GitHub](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/FlipFloop/Color-Drop/blob/master/index.html)

Why is this not working?

Plus: why are the theme and player being added to the game section as we choose the theme?

GitHub link: https://github.com/FlipFloop/Color-Drop

Thanks to all!

Comment: what exactly is not working? I am seeing a white box on black background when I choose Dark theme. I am running Chrome.

Comment: @Fabio look at the GitHub example

Comment: I am looking at it. What is it supposed to do? Both the snippet and the github example give the same result

Comment: @Fabio in GitHub I can't see the white block, can you?

Comment: #player has {position: absolute;} but #game is not positioned, so player IS apeparing, just on the bottom of the document, usually invisible (white on white). Try making #game have {position:relative;}.

Comment: http://imgur.com/6E2CDhs I can indeed

Comment: @bags still doesn't work for me (github) https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/FlipFloop/Color-Drop/blob/master/index.html

Comment: @bags IT WORKS NOW, THX!

Comment: @bags post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#player` has `position: absolute;` but `#game` is not positioned, so player IS appearing, just on the bottom of the document, usually invisible (white on white). Try making `#game` have `position:relative;`.

EDIT: @FlipFloop Posting this comment as an answer with a code snippet below, for completeness. Run full-screen and toggle the `position: relative;` of `#game` off and on to illustrate the problem/solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#options').change(function() { // NOTE: all themes have capital letters on colors
    if ($(this).val() === 'Dark') {
      $("#game").css("background-color", "black");
      $("#player").css({
        "background-color": "white" // using CSS function in case you want to add other stuff
      });
    }
  });

  $("#play").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#options").hide();
    $("#player").show();
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.block {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute
}
#game {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 550px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  margin: 2% 10%;
  position: relative;
}
#player {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#play {
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
#options {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trash Fall - Game</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- adding jQuery to the script -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="main_title">Color Drop</h1>

  <div id="game">

    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <select id="options">
      <option value="none">none (choose one in order to play)</option>
      <option value="Dark">Dark</option>
      <option value="Light">Light</option>
      <option value="Blue_White">Blue/White</option>
      <option value="Red_White">Red/White</option>
    </select>

    <div id="player"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use condition statements ie. switch or if/else if/else, in order to catch your option data. In your code you only looking for Dark value !

when I try this (I had Light condition), it works for Light value :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("ok");

  $('#options').change(function(){ // NOTE: all themes have capital letters on colors
      console.log("ok");
    if($(this).val() === 'Dark'){ 
      $("#game").css("background-color", "black");
      $("#player").css({
        "background-color": "white" // using CSS function in case you want to add other stuff
      });
    }
    if($(this).val() === 'Light'){ 
      $("#game").css("background-color", "white");
      $("#player").css({
        "background-color": "white" // using CSS function in case you want to add other stuff
      });
    }
  });

  $("#play").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#options").hide();
    $("#player").show();
  });


});
```